# Changing dynamically created button's background in WPF

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I have the following code to dynamically create and add a button to a panel:

```
StackPanel topPanel=...;
Button button=new Button();

button.Content="New Button "+topPanel.Children.Count;      

// Set button background to a red/yellow linear gradient
// Create a default background brush
var bgBrush=new LinearGradientBrush(new GradientStopCollection(
   new GradientStop[] {new GradientStop(Color.FromRgb(255,255,200),0.5),
                       new GradientStop(Color.FromRgb(255,200,200),0.5)}));
// Create a more intense mouse over background brush
var bgMouseOverBrush=new LinearGradientBrush(new GradientStopCollection(
   new GradientStop[] {new GradientStop(Color.FromRgb(255,255,100),0.5),
                       new GradientStop(Color.FromRgb(255,100,100),0.5)}));

// Set the button's background
button.Background=bgBrush;
// Dynamically, add the button to the panel
topPanel.Children.Add(button);
```

The problem is that when I move the mouse cursor over the button, it reverts to its previous light blue background. Now, I have read that what I need is a mouseover button trigger, but I have no idea how to do this programatically just for this button, alone. Basically, I want its background to change to `bgMouseOverBrush` when the mouse cursor is over it and back to `bgBrush` when it is not.

Answer (score 2):

Try  this:

```
    // In the constructor or any approp place
    button.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(b_MouseEnter);
    button.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler(b_MouseLeave);

    void b_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        button.Background=bgBrush;
    }

    void b_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        button.Background = bgMouseOverBrush;
    }
```

Hope that helps.

**EDIT**

Mouse Enter
[image: MouseOver]

Mouse Out
[image: Mouse Out]

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work. Apparently the button overrides the background set in the MouseEnter event handler right after it is changed with the IsMouseOver dependency property trigger, which sets the background to the default chrome. A style trigger or something like it is needed here.

Comment: Hi Michael, I actually tested with the same gradient values and found that it worked just fine (Screen Captures attached to the Answer). Are you sure you are not resetting the Style / Background values somewhere else?

Comment: Are you trying this with Aero enabled on Vista or Windows 7? I am using Windows 7 with Aero enabled

Comment: Nope, I was trying on WinXP. Currently do not have access to a Win7 machine, will test it out at the earliest possible.