# Change rectangle background on mouse hover

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have a rectangle with no background and I want to give it a background gradient when the user hovers their mouse over it, and then remove the gradient when the mouse leaves the rectangle.

Please can someone post the code that is needed for this, and tell me where to put it in the .cs/xaml file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This:

```xml
<Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black">
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Transparent" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <!-- Change ImageSource to what image you want to use -->
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:/Users/Public/1.png" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```

(Note that if you set `Fill="Transparent"` on the Rectangle itself the Trigger will *not* work because of [dependency property value precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))

Comment: This works perfectly, however I have discovered that I do not need to use an image as I can do a gradient in xaml. How would I modify this to be a gradient instead of an image?

The gradient I want is:

`<Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush  StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#eee" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>`

Comment: Just change the content of the `Setter.Value` in the trigger to your `LinearGradientBrush`.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!

Another problem though, I have a label on top of the rectangle, and I want the rectangle fill to change when hovering on the rectangle or the label, how do I do this?

Comment: This is out of the scope of this question, create another one please if you cannot figure that out or find help in other SO questions.

Comment: Ok done - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203173/hover-over-label-change-rectangle-background-gradient

Answer (score 0):

This answer is close to yours I believe.  They are setting the background to a brush instead of an image. - [Changing dynamically created button's background in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423471/changing-dynamically-created-buttons-background-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

You could add two `Triggers` for `IsMouseOver` property: when it is `true` (ie mouse is over the rectangle), here I change the background to Blue, otherwise Red!

```
<Rectangle.Resources>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </Trigger>
</Rectangle.Resources>
```

Comment: Triggers belong to a style, not just resources.

Comment: Additionaly rectangles have no `Background`.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way must be something like this (beware, no good style):

```
<Image>
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="myimage.png"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Comment: Not me, but the point of the question was that a rectangle is being used, not an ImageControl which is rather different, so i suppose that was the reason. Edit: Why did it get retracted i wonder...

Comment: @H.B.: I believe the rectangle in the original question refers not to the exact control name (having it exactly Rectangle doesn't see to be important), but just to the geometric form of the the control.

Comment: Well, then that part would be rather redundant, show me any controk which **isn't** rectangular.

Comment: @H.B.: actually, when I was quite inexperienced in UI programming, I tended to refer to the controls or other UI elements just as "rectangles". :-)

Comment: I literally dragged and dropped the 'rectangle' from the toolbox in the designer, hence calling it a rectangle...

Answer (score 0):

The way to change background color to gradient for rectangle:

```
<Rectangle Width="128" Height="128" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black">
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Fill">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF2824A0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF78B9DD" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter> 
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```