# Hover over label change rectangle background gradient

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, styles

I have a rectange with several labels and images over it, and I have it so that when the user hovers their mouse over the rectangle the background changes to a gradient:

```xml
<Rectangle Height="88" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="54,28,0,0" Name="rectangle2" VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="327" Cursor="Hand">
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Transparent" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#eee" Offset="1" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```

However, when I hover over one of the labels that is over the rectangle the background gradient does not show.

I want to make it so that the gradient shows when hovering over the labels as well as the rectangle.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "over" you mean overlayed and not above you can wrap the contents in a Grid (for above you could do this as well i guess, but you should define rows & columns) and use a [`DataTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.DataTrigger.aspx) which triggers if the mouse is over the wrapping grid and not only the rectangle itself, e.g.:

```xml
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black">
        <Rectangle.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Transparent" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Fill">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <!-- Brush here -->
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Rectangle.Style>
    </Rectangle>
    <Label Name="label" Content="This is a Label" />
</Grid>
```

Alternatively if the label is overlayed you can make mouse events pass through the Label by setting `IsHitTestVisible` to `false`.

Comment: In the designer the labels are set to be above the rectangle. (Rectangle is 'send to back' option in the 'order' context menu)

This solution with the grid works great! Thanks.

Comment: I added another method which should work even more easily unless you need the mouse to be able to interact with the label.

Comment: I do not require interaction, so your second method works great, thanks again.

EDIT: Scratch that, some of the labels do require interaction, so the first method works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Because the other elements are on top of the rectangle, I think you will need to hook to the PreviewMouseMove event for the rectangle.

UIELement.PreviewMouseMove: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmousemove.aspx

Preview events: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752279.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but turning `IsHitTestVisible` to `false` solves my problem.